# Flatness for pushouts/amalgamations of rings

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

In this question I am working in the category of unital but not necessarily commutative rings.

> > Let $R$ and $T$ be rings with a common subring $U$ and suppose that $R$ and $T$ are flat as right $U$-modules. Must the pushout of $R$ and $T$ along $U$ (ie the amalgamated free product) be flat as a right $R$-module?

Here is what Google told me. If $R$ and $T$ are faithfully flat over $U$ then the anewer is yes and you even get faithful flatness by a result of Cohn. I also found out that the answer is yes if the inclusions of $U$ are categorical epis. Bergman proved the answer is yes if $U$ is commutstive.